# How to invoke-sqlcmd (or sqlcmd.exe) with AAD+MultiFactorAuth

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, sqlcmd, multi-factor-authentication, invoke-sqlcmd

All the docs and help threads I can find reference connection strings with Authentication=ActiveDirectoryIntegrated to hit SQL with AAD integration.  If I'm using SSMS I can also choose "Active Directory Universal" which gives a prompt if MultiFactorAuth (MFA) is required.

I want to use powershell to invoke-sqlcmd, or even sqlcmd.exe directly -- do either support an MFA flow?  How else can I get commandline queries against an AAD-enabled MFA-enabled SQLAzure instance?

```
invoke-sqlcmd : Failed to authenticate the user NT Authority\Anonymous Logon in Active Directory
(Authentication=ActiveDirectoryIntegrated).
Error code 0xCAA2000C; state 10
AADSTS50079: The user is required to use multi-factor authentication.
Trace ID: 54f0cb31-2f0f-4137-b142-b312a6cd441b
Correlation ID: 70204904-576c-4db5-9c3b-6ccd7fe6b409
Timestamp: 2017-02-09 22:56:39Z
```

I've seen https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication, and everything was working fine right up until MFA either was applied, or when it realized it was time to re-auth and prompt.

If there is a way for me to cache creds so ActiveDirectoryIntegrated generally works, and I just need to re-auth and re-cache when it decides it is time to force an MFA prompt I'm also open to that.

Comment: If I login to windows with a Pin or smartcard and not a user/pass, ActiveDirectoryIntegrated is ok.  still interested if there is another flow here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to use powershell to invoke-sqlcmd, or even sqlcmd.exe directly -- do either support an MFA flow?

No. As far as I know, the SSMS is the only tool currently enabled for MFA through Active Directory Universal Authentication.( refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-ssms-mfa-authentication#universal-authentication-limitations-for-sql-database-and-sql-data-warehouse))

If you have any idea or suggestion about Azure SQL database, you can submit them from [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database).

Answer (score 2):

[Beginning with version 15.0.1, sqlcmd utility and bcp utility support Active Directory Interactive authentication with MFA.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication#additional-considerations)